# Starting grid column from half of the column

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to start grid column from half of the very first column.

I tried `grid-start-column` with different values but it's not working. Basically, it should be like following:

```
grid-column: 0.5/7
```

I know this is not the valid code, but just for explanation I write that.

Is it possible to start a column from the half of the column?

Comment: it's possible but not in a generic way, share your specific code to get accurate answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to start a column from the half of the column?

No. It is not.

Let's say you have a grid container with five columns and want to start spanning from halfway inside the first column (`grid-column: 1.5 / 5` ). This won't work because you're not starting at a column line. More technically, the `grid-row-*` and `grid-column-*` properties [accept only integers](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement) as values.

However, there is a simple workaround:

- Instead of five columns use 10 columns.
- Then start spanning at the third column (`grid-column: 3 / 10`).

This creates an equivalent layout, which looks the same visually, but with more precise control of the columns.

More details here: [Changing div heights using CSS grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47558918/3597276)